# SOAPUI Error: Attempted read from closed stream for JSON POST to redirect to GET after 302

Tags: rest, testing, groovy, soapui

I am trying to test a Rest service API Method for adding/updating member record, with following details:
**Parameters**:
post-body (JSON document) - Object representing a member and the source of their data
**Content Type**:
application/json
**Returns**:
Success
HTTP 302 - Redirect to Get

When I m trying to test In SOAPUI, I am getting following error:

SOAPUI LOG:

```
Wed Dec 19 11:16:02 EST 2012:DEBUG:Attempt 1 to execute request
Wed Dec 19 11:16:02 EST 2012:DEBUG:Sending request: POST http://.............................................................. HTTP/1.1
Wed Dec 19 11:16:02 EST 2012:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Wed Dec 19 11:16:02 EST 2012:DEBUG:Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
Wed Dec 19 11:16:02 EST 2012:DEBUG:Connection closed
Wed Dec 19 11:16:02 EST 2012:DEBUG:Connection shut down
Wed Dec 19 11:16:02 EST 2012:ERROR:An error occured [Attempted read from closed stream.], see error log for details
Wed Dec 19 11:16:02 EST 2012:ERROR:Exception in request: java.net.UnknownHostException: ANY URL as ENDPOINT
Wed Dec 19 11:16:02 EST 2012:ERROR:An error occured [ANY URL...], see error log for details
Wed Dec 19 11:16:02 EST 2012:INFO:Error getting response for [Rest_Srvc_Member_Put.Rsrc_Member_Put:Rest_Req_Member_Put]; java.net.UnknownHostException: ANY URL as ENDPOINT
```

ERROR LOG:

```
Wed Dec 19 11:16:02 EST 2012:ERROR:java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
   java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toByteArray(EntityUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity.<init>(BufferedHttpEntity.java:60)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpMethodSupport.getResponseBody(HttpMethodSupport.java:281)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.support.methods.ExtendedPostMethod.getResponseBody(ExtendedPostMethod.java:128)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.SinglePartHttpResponse.<init>(SinglePartHttpResponse.java:49)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.HttpPackagingResponseFilter.httpRequest(HttpPackagingResponseFilter.java:85)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.HttpPackagingResponseFilter.afterAbstractHttpResponse(HttpPackagingResponseFilter.java:50)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.afterRequest(AbstractRequestFilter.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:297)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Wed Dec 19 11:16:02 EST 2012:ERROR:java.net.UnknownHostException: ...URL
   java.net.UnknownHostException: URL
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:242)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:274)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:236)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:345)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.followRedirects(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:357)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:256)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help to resolve this issue is highly appreciated, please. I am using SOAPUI Pro 4.5.1
Please help at earliest......

Comment: I think your endpoint is not valid. Have you checked that?

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a mapping of the IP addresse to the host name in the following file: "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts".